# about ef core winforms net framework support problem

Tags: winforms, xamarin, entity-framework-core

I want to develop a general project, the desktop application must be .Net Framework and I will use EF Core 5.0 in the background and the libraries must be .net standard so that they are compatible with xamarin and Asp.net Core. Everything is fine, but the net framework does not support 2.1. How do I overcome this problem?.

Answer (score 1):

NET 5.0 desktop toolbox has problems. I am someone who uses Devexpress and it does not come out in vehicles. I asked Devexpress and they said they have microsoft-side problems. I didn't know what to do. Syncfusion components do not look the same, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop Winforms application using .NET 5. It is replacement of .NET Framework which become deprecated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/?view=netdesktop-5.0